# Yup Was Not Working With Formik and also not provide any type of error

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Yup Validation Not Working I Also tried Like This `import Yup from 'yup'` But Still Not Working.., when I create a simple validate Function without YUP it was worked fine. but when I use YUP that time Validation Not Work.
**Added Form Component**

```
import React from 'react';
import { useFormik } from 'formik';
import * as Yup from 'yup';

const initialValues = {
    name : "",
    surname : "",
    address : ""
}

const validateSchema = Yup.object({
 name: Yup.string().required('This Field is Required'),
 surname: Yup.string().required('This Field is Required'),
 address: Yup.string().required('This Field is Required')
});

const  onSubmit =  values =>{                        
    console.log('FormData->',values);
}

function Form() {
    const formik = useFormik({
        initialValues ,
        onSubmit ,
        validateSchema 
    })
    return (
        <div className="container x col-md-4 col-md-offset-4"  >
         <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit} >   
            <div className="form-group">
                <input autoComplete="off" onBlur={formik.handleBlur} onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                value={formik.values.name}  name="name"  className="name form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter A Name" />
                <small> 
                    {formik.touched.name && formik.errors.name ? <div className="error"> {formik.errors.name}  </div> : null} 
                </small>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">
                <input autoComplete="off" onBlur={formik.handleBlur} onChange={formik.handleChange} 
                value={formik.values.surname}  name="surname" className="surname form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter A Surname" />
                <small> { formik.touched.surname && formik.errors.surname ? <div className="error"> {formik.errors.surname}  </div> : null} </small>
            </div>
            <div className="form-group">    
                <input autoComplete="off" onBlur={formik.handleBlur} onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.address}
                  name="address" className="address form-control-lg" placeholder="Enter A Address" />
                <small> {formik.touched.address  &&  formik.errors.address ? <div className="error"> {formik.errors.address}  </div> : null} </small>
            </div>
            <button className="btn btn-danger" >Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    )
}
export default Form;
```

Comment: Where is the error from? Webpack build process? Can you share the full stack trace?

Comment: Failed to compile.
./src/Form.js
Attempted import error: 'required' is not exported from 'yup' (imported as 'Yup').

Comment: I Edit my question and also improve some code so this error was going and  YUP validation not worked

Comment: Did you mean the error has gone? But the validation doesn't work? If so, can you show your form component as well?

Comment: i added my form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The valid option here is `validationSchema` not `validateSchema`. Just set the right one:

```js
const validationSchema = Yup.object({
  // ...
});

useFormik({
  // ...
  validationSchema
})
```

Answer (score 0):

To use formik and yup, first you have you do npm install yup and npm install formik. if your yarn user then do yarn add formik and yarn add yup.

after that follow this code.

```
import {Formik} from 'formik';
import * as yup from 'yup';
//functional component am using
export const Auth = () => {
const initialFormValue ={
email: '',password: '',};
const SignInSchema = yup.object().shape({
email: yup.string().email('Invalid Email').required('Email is Required'),
password: yup.string().min(5, 'Too Short').required('Password is Required'),
})
<Formik initialValues={initialFormValue} validationSchema={SignInSchema}
 onSubmit={values => console.log(values)}>
 {({values, errors, touched, handleChange, handleBlur,
handleSubmit,isSubmitting,
isValid}) => (
 <>
 <input name='email' type='email' handleChange={handleChange} value=
 {values.email} onBlur={handleBlur} label='Email' />
{errors.email && touched.email ? (<Error>{errors.email}</Error>): null}
<input name='password' type='password' handleChange={handleChange} value=
{values.password} onBlur={handleBlur} label='Password' />
{errors.password && touched.password ? (<Error>{errors.password}</Error>):
null}
<button onClick={handleSubmit} type="submit">Send</button>
 </>
) }
 </Formik>
)}
```

its not necessary for you to define initial value outside you can do inside formik too `<Formik initialValues={email: '', password: ''}> </Formik>`
i hope this will help you thank you.